# Takenoko growing bamboo when gardner lands on non-irrigated plot

Tags: takenoko

In the board game Takenoko, when the gardener moves onto a non-irrigated plot of a color (say green), do all adjacent, irrigated plots of that color (green) grow bamboo?

In the game manual, the text is as follows:

The player moves the gardener in a straight line, any number of plots in the direction of his choice. The gardener is only allowed to move over plots, not empty spaces between plots. He grows a section of bamboo on the plot where he finishes his move as well as on all directly adjacent plots of the same color. If a plot has bamboo at a height of four sections, then no section is added, because 4 sections is the maximum size of a bamboo shoot.
Note: Sections never grow in non-irrigated plots, even if the gardener finishes move on the plot or an adjacent plot.

The pictorial examples in the game manual only show the gardener landing on irrigated plots.

Because the instructions in the manual do not make mention of this scenario, if one takes the words literally, it seems that bamboo would grow on the irrigated plots. However, from a thematic perspective of the game, it seems that the gardener should only be able to work their magic on an irrigated plot, where the gardening effect radiates outward from that irrigated tile.

Of note: In the online version at boardgamearena.com, the mechanic functions where all adjacent irrigated plots grow bamboo, despite if the landing plot is irrigated or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the faq on board game geek is specifies that the gardener will grow bamboo on adjacent plots if they are irrigated regardless of the plot he landed being irrigated. What is important here is that the plot that is getting the bamboo growth is irrigated.

https://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Takenoko_FAQ

> If the plot the gardener is on is not irrigated, the bamboo will still grow on the adjacent plots of the same color if they are irrigated.

Comment: Good find. Thanks. Do you know how BGG comes to their conclusion? With this and in general? Is it just their own interpretation of the rules?

Comment: @coconn41 I do not, I just know that is what they had posted and it makes sense to me as growing bamboo just depends on the plot itself being irrigated.